# R calculate possible values of two variables

Tags: r, math

I'm trying to calculate all the possible values of a grid size (x by y) that lead to the same number of cells, so for example a 2x2 grid has a cell size of 4. I want the y to be half of the x, and the total to be, for example 4000. So I guess I want R to calculate all the possible positive integer values of x and y where

```
function (total) {
x*y=total
x/y=2 
x!=total 
y!= total.
}
```

I suppose one way to get positive integers and to consider different solutions would be to allow the total to be up to 10% larger than its original value (but not smaller, I need the grid to be at least as big as the total value I give), in which case the function could have two fields, tot (e.g. 4000) and tolerance (e.g. 10%). Total (as used in the sketch function above) than has to be between tot and (tot+tolerance*tot)

I have several cell sizes so 4000 is only one example. I'm trying to build a quick function which returns positive integers only and returns a matrix of Xs and Ys.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Your problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643129/split-screen-based-on-number-of-items-and-screen-ratio . If you just want a grid then flodel has given an excellent answer. If you want to create a grid that fits a specific viewport (like a certain window size), then check my answer to the referenced question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
possible.sizes <- function(total, tolerance) {

   min.total <- total
   max.total <- total * (1 + tolerance)

   min.y <- ceiling(sqrt(min.total/2))
   max.y <- floor(sqrt(max.total/2))

   if (max.y < min.y)
      return(data.frame(x=numeric(0), y=numeric(0)))

   y <- seq(min.y, max.y)
   x <- 2*y

   return(data.frame(x=x, y=y))
}

possible.sizes(4000, 0.1)
#    x  y
# 1 90 45
# 2 92 46
```